# MongoDB : Push or merge one lookup's result in other lookup's result

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 3 collection namely `constants`, `activities`, `applications` with mentioned properties.

Now, querying `constants` collection with `activities` and `activities` with `applications` with matching Id's. I am getting correct results. But now `activity_types` are shown at per data level.

But expecting the output should be at per `item` level inside `data` whichever is matching with item. Because `activities` are matching for Item and it should be shown in per item level not at data level. I tried with `$push` and `$group` but not getting expected results.

Constants

```
{
    _id: id
    value : {
        categories: [
            {
                id: 001,
                title: "test 1"
            },
            {
                id: 002,
                title: "test 2"
            },
            {
                id: 003,
                title: "test 3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Activity

```
{
    propert1: "",
    propert2: "",
    config: {
        agenda_item_category_ids: [ObjectId(001), ObjectId(002)]
    },
    activity_type_id: ObjectId(123)

}
{
    propert1: "",
    propert2: "",
    activity_type_id: ObjectId(456)
    config: {
        agenda_item_category_ids: [ObjectId(002)]
    }

}
```

applications

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(123),
    prop1: "",
    prop2: ""
}
{
    _id: ObjectId(456),
    prop1: "",
    prop2: ""
}
```

Current query

```
const results = await Constants.aggregate([
    {
        $match: query,
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$value.categories',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'activity',
            localField: 'value.categories.id',
            foreignField: 'config.agenda_item_category_ids',
            as: 'data',
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'applications',
            localField: 'items.activity_type_id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'activity_type',
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            category_id: '$value.categories.id',
            title: '$value.categories.title',
            description: '$value.categories.description',
            icon_src: '$value.categories.icon_src',
            data: 1,
            activity_type: 1,
        },
    },
]);
```

Current output

```
[
    {
        data: [
            {item1},
            {item2}
        ],
        activity_type,
        title
        _id
    },
    {
        data: [
            {item1},
            {item2}
        ],
        activity_type,
        title
        _id
    }
]
```

Expected output

```
[
    {
        data: [
            {
                item1,
                activity_type
            },
            {
                item2,
                activity_type
            }
        ],
        title
        _id
    },
]
```

Tried method

```
{
  "_id": "$_id",
  "activity_type": {
    "$push": "$activity_type"
  }
}
```